# Getting exception "duplicate transaction identifier " while using Transaction.Current.DependentClone

Tags: c#, multithreading, oracle, transactions, .net-3.5

I am creating a mechanism to bulk-insert (import) a lot of new records into a ORACLE database. I am using multiple threads and dependent transactions:

Creation of threads:

```
const int ThreadCount = 4;
using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
{
    List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>(threadCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < ThreadCount; i++)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(WorkerThread);
        thread.Start(Transaction.Current.DependentClone(DependentCloneOption.BlockCommitUntilComplete));
        threads.Add(thread);
    }
    threads.ForEach(thread => thread.Join());
    transaction.Complete();
}
```

The method that does the actual work:

```
private void WorkerThread(object transaction)
{
    using (DependentTransaction dTx = (DependentTransaction)transaction)
    using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope(dTx))
    {
         // The actual work, the inserts on the database, are executed here.
    }
}
```

During this operation, I get an exception of type `System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException` with the message `ORA-24757: duplicate transaction identifier`.

What am I doing wrong? Am I implementing the dependent transaction the incorrect way? Is it incompatible with Oracle? If so, is there a workarround?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about why u get this exception but a work around might be:

```
const int ThreadCount = 4;
using (var connection = new OracleConnection(MyConnectionstring))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
    {
        List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>(ThreadCount);
        for (int i = 0; i < ThreadCount; i++)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(WorkerThread);
            thread.Start(transaction);
            threads.Add(thread);
        }
        threads.ForEach(thread => thread.Join());

        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

and the working class would look something like:

```
private void WorkerThread(object transaction)
{
    OracleTransaction trans = (OracleTransaction) transaction;

    using (OracleCommand command = trans.Connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO mytable (x) values (1)  ";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: While I apreciate the effort, it does not realy help. Since a connection cannot be shared by multiple threads, the connection will "lock" the connection , while executing its (non)query. This results in an even slower solution than a single threaded environment...

Comment: I thought about your solution some more. It will only speed up things more and more when the 'preparation' part (like importing, collecting data, etc.) becomes larger and larger. Not the threaded INSERT will speed it up, but the fact that the 'preparation' part can be seperated over multiple threads. After a record is 'prepared' (parallel) it can be writen to the database, which will become, in your case, a queue of locked INSERT operations.